# With a Composer repository, how can one determine reverse package requirements?

Tags: jenkins, composer-php

For a given version of a package, I need to find those packages which Require it.

I can re-invent the wheel by crafting some kind of parser to go against our Satis repo's packages.json but surely there's an easier way that's already present in the Composer API?

The use case for this is a build pipeline I am constructing on our Jenkins CI server that responds to commits to our top-level master composer project which is the moving version to we need to retrieve and assemble (via composer require) each package in our Satis repo that has a dependency, applying fuzzy version matching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have internal knowledge about the Composer API - my approach is to use the published CLI interface to get the job done, trying to avoid fancy stuff, because the Composer project still is heavily work in progess. That being said:

You cannot compile a list of "this package A is being used by all these packages" in the general case, because that would mean that you have to scan ALL packages existing in the world. That job would never end.

However, using Satis will compile a list of packages detected to use a certain package, which is rendered in the HTML template just for information. So for a reasonable small world it is possible to detect the dependencies and create a reverse dependency map. But I don't think this is a reliable feature within Composer, because for the usual use case Composer will only evaluate forward dependencies, never reverse. There is no use case within Composer to create these relations, chances are high Satis also doesn't expose them in the regular case.

You can however try to output something that is more machine readable than the rendered HTML to get the "packages using this" info - it is passed as an array variable into the template. Shouldn't be too difficult to output something else.